# radtextbox avoid object throwing Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, object-reference, radtextbox

Which is a better code to avoid throwing Object reference not set to an instance of an object
when using Telerik Radtextbox? Are both codes below the same? Can I set a default value to avoid nullreference from throwing?

```
protected void btnAddSAles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{  
   string orderName = Ordername.Text;
}
```

or

```
protected void btnAddSAles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{    
   TextBox b = item.FindControl("Ordername") as TextBox;            
   string box1 = b.text;            
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @GrantWinney it throws an error when assigning the textbox value to a string. Is there a way to avoid throwing nullexception? Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's not the same issue.

Comment: @GrantWinney

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am *assuming* `FindControl` is returning `null` from the `as` cast you're trying to make. I assume (again) it isn't finding a control named `Ordername`, hence you are trying to access a `Text` property on a `null` object, which causes the `NullReferenceException`.

What you should do is:

1. Check why there is no control named `Ordername`, as im assuming there should be one
2. If the control which invoked the `Button.Click` *may not* always be a `TextBox` object, add a nullity check:

   ```
   protected void btnAddSAles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
   {    
      TextBox b = item.FindControl("Ordername") as TextBox;      
      if (b != null)
      {      
         string box1 = b.text;
      }           
   }
   ```

Comment: The Ordername textbox is existing on my page but then there are times wherein the nullreference error is thrown. Do you know any way to replicate this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

The two code samples are not the same.

The first sample won't throw that exception, unless you explicitly set `Ordername = null` somewhere in your code, which I doubt you did.

The second sample will throw because you're trying to cast a `RadTextBox` to a `TextBox` (I'm assuming, since you're asking about `RadTextBox`), which results in `b` being `null`.

If you want to avoid the possibility of a null reference exception, then you have to check for `null` before accessing properties on the control:

```
protected void btnAddSAles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{    
   TextBox b = item.FindControl("Ordername") as TextBox;  

   if (b != null)
   {
       // do something with b.Text;
   }
}
```

The real issue here is that you're casting to the wrong type. The `RadTextBox` does not derive from the native `TextBox` control. You have to cast to a `RadTextBox`.

```
protected void btnAddSAles_click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{    
   RadTextBox b = item.FindControl("Ordername") as RadTextBox;  

   if (b != null)
   {
       // do something with b.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you
is string orderName = Ordername.Text 
same as    
TextBox b = item.FindControl("Ordername") as TextBox 
string orderName = b.Text?

Comment: This issue is actually intermittent. So there are times wherein nullreference throws because it could not find the radtextbox but it does not happen all the time. Do you have an idea which scenario may throw this error? Does a postback may cause this issue or something to do with sessionstate? Thank you so much for helping